# How to implement Face Detection for Human Being only in Android?

Tags: android, face-recognition, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I want to create an app where User can mark his Attendance by showing his face on Camera. I have got the Firebase Sample App for Face Detection.
[Firebase Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart)

But this is identifying user by the Real user and also from my Phone Gallery. I want to detect only for real Human Being

Answer (score 0):

The sample app you linked is not provided by Firebase, but rather by ML Kit. ML Kit does not support what you want to achieve (identifying a real human being and marking their attendance).

Comment: So Do you have any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on face recognition or liveness detection. You may want to search online for possible options.